# nginx reverse proxy for application

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I use nginx for reverse proxy with domain name. I've some application publish on IIS and i want to proxy different location name for each application.
For example;
Domain name on nginx :

```
example.com.tr
```

application end points for app:

```
1.1.1.1:10
1.1.1.2:10
```

upstream for app in nginx.conf:

```
upstream app_1 {
  least_conn;

  server 1.1.1.1:10;
  server 1.1.1.2:10;

}


server {
        listen                443 ssl;
        server_name           example.com.tr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        ssl_certificate       /etc/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key   /etc/cert.key;


    location  /app_1/ {


        proxy_pass      http://app_1/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-REAL-SCHEME $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;




        access_log /etc/nginx/log/access.log;
        error_log /etc/nginx/log/error.log;
}
}
```

When I try to access example.com.tr/app_1/  , I can access application but not all data.
I inspected this site and so many requests of application were failed.
All requests sended to example.com.tr/uri instead of  example.com.tr/app_1/uri. How can I fix this ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need a transparent path proxy setup. Means NGINX should use the requested URI without removing the matched location from it.

```
        proxy_pass      http://app_1;
```

Remove the tailing slash to tell NGINX not to do so. Using an `upstream` definition is great but make sure you apply `keepalive`.

Comment: After remove slash , I could'nt access the site. I think it's about redirecting. After first access this site, site send  requests for loading css file or functions. After this request arrive nginx and nginx sending without uri.  Then requests are failed.

Comment: That means your problem it not related to NGINX not sending the full URI to your backend. Please update your post with error logs from NGINX and IIS to validate what the real issue is. With the config above NGINX would proxy `example.com.tr/app_1/` to `1.1.1.1:10/app_1`.

Comment: Actually I want to proxy example.com.tr/app_1/ to 1.1.1.1:10.

Comment: yes that is clear. Does your app can handle `/app_1` or do you need to remove it from the proxied URI? To help you in this case we would need to see the logs of NGINX as well as from the application we are proxying to find the issue.